# Jquery bind('beforeunload') doesn't work in Chrome popup

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

I'm using the jQuery bind event bind('beforeunload') to call a JS function to check for unsaved changes and it works fine in all the three browsers that I test with. However when I try the same in a popup/child window, it doesn't seem to work in Chrome. IE 11 and Firefox works fine. Any suggestions/would be helpful.

```
qj(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
       alert("test...");
    });
```

Comment: have you tired 'on' function instead of bind?

Comment: `$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
`